# Getting the users of an FOSUserBundle Group (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have been struggling with this question for the past couple of hours and haven't been able to find anything.

I have configured the FOSUserBundle and have the groups activated correctly and working. However, the user-group relation is defined as follows in the User class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Netlabs\UserBundle\Entity\Group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups;
```

and in the Group class, I do not even have a $user list defined. I tried loads of "normal" things like creating a $users variable in my Group class and defining it's relation to the User object, but it is not playing nice with the FOSUserBundle (every time, it creates a NEW table to create the relation, when there is already one in place). For example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Netlabs\UserBundle\Entity\Group", inversedBy="groups", cascade={"all"})
 * 
 */
protected $users;
```

Any suggestions ?

Again, my main goal is : I want to be able to do Group->getUsers()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Group class, your targetEntity must be User and not Group. Furthermore, try to add an inversedBy rule for the $groups attributs and modifie inversedBy in mappedBy for $users.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Netlabs\UserBundle\Entity\Group", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups;
```

And

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Netlabs\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="groups")
 * 
 */
protected $users;
```

Comment: After modifying the code as to your suggestions and running "doctrine:generate:entities" and "doctrine:schema:update --force", it still creates a new table "group_user", instead of using the "fos_user_user_group" that it's supposed to.

Comment: With a ManyTo§any relation, you must create a new table. It's the only way to save the relations between objects.

Comment: I know, but the FOSUserBundle already creates a table called "fos_user_user_group" which fullfills exactly that purpose. There should only be 1 table, not 2.

Comment: Did you try to add @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group") above the $users attribut ?

Comment: Is there not exactly what you want to do ? [Click](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

Comment: If I do that, I get "The table with name 'fos_user_user_group' already exists." when I run doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: Try [This](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) with a mappedBy. It should works.

Comment: wooot, that works !. Thank you very much. I knew it was something as stupid as that :)

Comment: If you modify your initial answer, I can accpet it :)